# Eigen MatrixXi to VectorXi conversion

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a MatrixXi, say

```
 [0, 1, 2]
 [0, 2, 3]
 [4, 7, 6]
 [4, 6, 5]
 [0, 4, 5]
 [0, 5, 1]
 [1, 5, 6]
```

I get a part of it by doing:

```
MatrixXi MR = F.middleRows(first, last);
```

with first and last at will. Now I'd like to turn those n rows into a column VectorXi, like:

```
   [0, 
    1, 
    2,
    0, 
    2, 
    3]
```

possibly without using a for loop. I've tried:

```
VectorXi VRT(MR.rows() * MR.cols());
VRT.tail(MR.rows() * MR.cols()) = MR.array();
```

But I get:

```
Assertion failed: (rows == this->rows() && cols == this->cols() && "DenseBase::resize() does not actually allow to resize."), function resize, file /Users/max/Developer/Stage/Workspace/AutoTools3D/dep/libigl/external/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h, line 257.
```

How do I get that? I'm using Eigen before v4 so I cannot use reshape...
Thank you

Comment: Note that Eigen is column-major. The order of values that you want isn't the order in which they are stored in memory. We could build something with ```Eigen::Map``` and inner stride but at this point it is really just easier to loop manually

Comment: Those matrix rows stacked in a vector horizontally are fine too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by chtz, this works:

```cpp
Eigen::VectorXi VR(MR.size());
Eigen::MatrixXi::Map(VR.data(), MR.cols(), MR.rows()) =
      MR.transpose();
```

Comment: Why wouldn't a RowMajor Map on `VRT.data()` work here?

Comment: @chtz you're right. Didn't occur to me to map the left side